# Monitor vim messages in real-time, inside an independent buffer

Tags: vim, macvim

I am working on a vim plugin and as part of that I am testing various things like "auto-groups" and events where I can hook bits and pieces in general. While things are running I am using functions that output various debug messages using the `echom` command. The problem is once I want to have a look at the output, I need to type `:message` and then keep hitting a key until the end of the messages appear, so I can see what was the last message.

Is there a workaround for this? Like, is there a plugin that would help me see the messages stream in realtime inside a separate buffer?

Thanks.
(OSX, MacVim)

Comment: Yeah, I spent some time trying to figure out what the "-1" means and when you get it :)

Comment: You could try starting vim with option `-Vlogfile.txt`, and then either use a `tail -f logfile.txt` in separate terminal window or open `logfile.txt` in Vim with a `:setlocal autoread` (or any of the various tail plugins for vim).  However, Vim doesn't seem to flush the logfile very frequently, so you will be a bit "behind" in the log... 

Also note that when you do `:messages` in Vim, you can go directly to the last message by hitting `G` and use other navigation keys (see `:help messages`).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `:echom` directly, write a little `s:Log(message)` function.  It should switch to your log buffer, then append `a:message` at the bottom (or the top, if you like).  Switch back to the current buffer and `:execute "echom" a:message`.

If you also want to see regular messages in your log buffer, you could use `:redir` to capture the messages, then append them to your log buffer on a CursorHold event.  This is more complicated, and it would tie up one of your named buffers.

```
:help :wincmd
:help :put
:help append()
:help :redir
:help CursorHold
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `:echomsg` and `:messages` is fine most of the time. If you need something more elaborate, have a look at the [Decho - Vim script internal debugger](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=120) plugin. It can capture log messages in a separate window.

For hairy parts, no amount of log output will be enough; you can then launch the built-in interactive debugging; see `:help debug-scripts`.

Comment: You had a typo: `:echosmg` -> `:echomsg`

Comment: @CharlesJie: Yep, and another one. Fixed.